# how to limit inbound in v2ray to a single device

Tags: inbound

I'm using a v2ray server I want each client user can have ability to access the internet just with one device and he can't use multiple devices to use the connection that I provide for him
please let me know if you have solution

I have tested several x-ui forks that claims their x-ui can provide me that ability but none of them work for me

Answer (score 1):

This **[Script](https://github.com/net-pioneer/v2ray-connection-limiter/blob/main/main.py)** can help you. Of course, if you create multiple users with different UIDs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In 6 steps:

1. apt install python3
2. pip3 install requests
3. pip3 install schedule
4. apt install net-tools
5. copy [main.py](https://github.com/net-pioneer/v2ray-connection-limiter/blob/main/main.py) file to your server
6. nohup python3 main.py &
   Maybe you need run these commands with sudo keyword

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but seems like no matter what i do, the column $3 is always 0 for all records so the return value is null.

Comment: The server is up and the specific port is working well. the $3 column is in this line of code:  netstate_data =  os.popen("netstat -np 2>/dev/null | grep :"+str(user_port)+" | awk '{if($3!=0) print $5;}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head").read();